# Adding multiple reactions to a message discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So the code show below is meant to send an embeded message to the discord channel the command was sent in. Once there it is to add emojis of the number 1 to 3 as reactions.

```
    # Start
    @client.command()
    async def start(self, ctx):
        # Main Message
        em = discord.Embed(title="Welcome to the Escape Room Test")
        em.add_field(name="To Continue React to the 1.", value="Ignore this", inline=False)
        message = await ctx.channel.send(embed=em)
        # Add Reactions
        number_of_responses = 3
        for counter in range(number_of_responses):
            await message.add_reaction(emoji_numbers[counter])
    # End Start
```

```
emoji_numbers = ["1️⃣", "2️⃣", "3️⃣", "4️⃣", "5️⃣", "6️⃣", "7️⃣", "8️⃣", "9️⃣"]
```

However after adding the first emoji I get this error and havent been able to find a way to get past it. Any suggestions would be amazing. Thanks.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/aab_dev/aaa_NewDev/EscapeRoomBot/bot.py", line 21, in <module>
    client.run("CLIENT-TOKEN-WAS-HERE")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 574, in run
    return task.result()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 494, in _silence_gathered
    fut.result()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 482, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 404, in connect
    await self._connect()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 369, in _connect
    await self.ws.poll_event()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 447, in poll_event
    await self.received_message(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 401, in received_message
    func(data)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 391, in parse_message_reaction_add
    emoji = PartialEmoji(animated=emoji_data['animated'], id=emoji_id, name=emoji_data['name'])
KeyError: 'animated'
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x055704D0>
```

Comment: How do you run the bot?

Comment: Perhaps try making the for loop for adding reactions an async for loop?
`async for counter in range(number_of_resonses):`

Comment: Sadly the Async doesnt work and I have a main file that will run the bot.

Answer (score 1):

That code worked, but I edited it little bit.

Your code:

```
@client.command()
async def start(self, ctx):
    # Main Message
    em = discord.Embed(title="Welcome to the Escape Room Test")
    em.add_field(name="To Continue React to the 1.", value="Ignore this", inline=False)
    # Add Reactions
    number_of_responses = 3
    emoji_numbers = ["1️⃣", "2️⃣", "3️⃣", "4️⃣", "5️⃣", "6️⃣", "7️⃣", "8️⃣", "9️⃣"]

    message = await ctx.send(embed=em)
    for i in range(number_of_responses):
        await message.add_reaction(emoji_numbers[i])
```

Comment: you missed `len()` in your `for` loop.